# Constraint generic by generic

Tags: swift, generics

Can someone help with solution, as i know described in bottom not passable by any variant (or not???), but maybe someone know very close solution?

P.S. Plz see description in code comments.

```swift
import Foundation

public struct HTTPRequest {
    // ...
}

public struct HTTPResponse {
    // ...
}

public class Router<SuccessResponse, FailureResponse: Swift.Error> {

    internal typealias Encoder = (Result<SuccessResponse, FailureResponse>) -> HTTPResponse
    internal typealias Responder = (HTTPRequest) -> HTTPResponse

    private let encoder: Encoder
    internal private(set) var responders: [String: Responder]

    internal init(encoder: @escaping Encoder) {
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.responders = [:]
    }

    // For me, is not correct! Description further...
    public func on(_ path: String, using closure: @escaping (HTTPRequest) -> Result<SuccessResponse, FailureResponse>) {
        responders[path] = { request in
            let result = closure(request)
            return self.encoder(result)
        }
    }

    // It's correct way, in usege, in this variant, you can't use different subtypes of SuccessResponse and FailureResponse, only one concrate type!
    // BUT I can't set constraint on SuccessResponse and FailureResponse as this should be a Protocol and in result we have error `... constrained to non-protocol, non-class type ...`
    public func on<S: SuccessResponse, F: FailureResponse>(_ path: String, using closure: @escaping (HTTPRequest) -> Result<S, F>) { // Type 'S, ''F' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'FailureResponse'
        responders[path] = { request in
            let result = closure(request)
            return self.encoder(result)
        }
    }

}
```

Usage example, you cannot use any ApiSuccess or ApiFailure, only concrete type constrained by other generic:

```swift
protocol ApiSuccess {
    // ...
}
protocol ApiFailure {
    // ...
}

enum Endpoint1Success: ApiSuccess {
    case ok
    case empty
}
enum Endpoint1Failure: ApiFailure {
    case not
    case internalError
}


let router = Router<ApiSuccess, ApiFailure> { result -> HTTPResponse in
    switch result {
    case .success(let apiSuccess):
        // apiSuccess encoded to HTTPResponse
        return HTTPResponse()
    case .failure(let apiFailure):
        // apiFailure encoded to HTTPResponse
        return HTTPResponse()
    }
}

router.on("/ok") { request -> Result<Endpoint1Success, Endpoint1Failure> in
    return .success(.ok)
}

router.on("/not") { request -> Result<Endpoint1Success, Endpoint1Failure> in
    return .failure(.not)
}
```

Or maybe is not correct way?

Comment: In other words, you want `Router` to be _variant_ on `SuccessResponse` and `FailureResponse`?

Comment: Swift doesn't have much generic variance support. The only place where it supports variance is arrays, as far as I know. I doubt this is possible.

Comment: I append usage example. About "Swift doesn't have much generic variance support. The only place where it supports variance is arrays, as far as I know. I doubt this is possible." apparently it is, but maybe there are other possibilities for a similar implementation? Plus, it’s strange that there is no such possibility in swift.

Comment: Your given use case doesn't really work though. In order for it to be used as the second type parameter of `Router`, `ApiFailure` must conform to `Error`, but protocols cannot conform to protocols, only concrete types can.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is generic variance, which is only natively supported for arrays.

So here's a workaround for your usage example. But before that, your example needs to be fixed first, as it doesn't currently compile. `ApiFailures` should be a class conforming to `Error` and `Endpoint1Failure` should be a class as well. Its cases should be rewritten to `static let`s.

The workaround is to only use the non-generic `on` method, and write the caller like this:

```
router.on("/ok") { request in
    return Result<Endpoint1Success, Endpoint1Failure>.success(.ok)
        .map { $0 }.mapError { $0 }
}
```

Essentially, you add `.map { $0 }.mapError { $0 }` after every return statement. This is the way you cast from `Result<S, F>` to `Result<ApiSuccess, ApiFailure>`. If you don't want to write this all the time, you can extract this into an extension:

```
extension Result where Success : ApiSuccess, Failure : ApiFailure {
    func toGeneralApiResult() -> Result<ApiSuccess, ApiFailure> {
        map { $0 }.mapError { $0 }
    }
}
```

This cast is actually unavoidable, even if you could constrain your `S` and `F` parameters. The only difference is where you do this cast. If you could constrain `S` and `F`, you would cast `result` before passing it to `encoder`. In this workaround you're just doing it on the caller's side.

Answer (score 0):

After long research, i was found this pinch: **https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13012** AND '**Generalized supertype constraints**' looks like needed.
As i can see is *accepted for implementation (or not) on 19 Nov 2019* and in result should to await to Swift 6+.